# scrapy- how to stop Redirect (302)

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a url using Scrapy. But it redirects me to page that doesn't exist.

```
Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.shop.inonit.in/mobile/Products/Inonit-Home-Decor--Knick-Knacks-Cushions/Shor-Sharaba/Andaz-Apna-Apna-Cushion-Cover/1275197> from <GET http://www.shop.inonit.in/Products/Inonit-Home-Decor--Knick-Knacks-Cushions/Shor-Sharaba/Andaz-Apna-Apna-Cushion-Cover/pid-1275197.aspx>
```

The problem is http://www.shop.inonit.in/Products/Inonit-Home-Decor--Knick-Knacks-Cushions/Shor-Sharaba/Andaz-Apna-Apna-Cushion-Cover/pid-1275197.aspx exists, but http://www.shop.inonit.in/mobile/Products/Inonit-Home-Decor--Knick-Knacks-Cushions/Shor-Sharaba/Andaz-Apna-Apna-Cushion-Cover/1275197 doesn't, so the crawler cant find this. I've crawled many other websites as well but didn't have this problem anywhere else. Is there a way I can stop this redirect?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Update: This is my spider class

```
class Inon_Spider(BaseSpider):
name = 'Inon'
allowed_domains = ['www.shop.inonit.in']

start_urls = ['http://www.shop.inonit.in/Products/Inonit-Gadget-Accessories-Mobile-Covers/-The-Red-Tag/Samsung-Note-2-Dead-Mau/pid-2656465.aspx']

def parse(self, response):

    item = DealspiderItem()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    title = hxs.select('//div[@class="aboutproduct"]/div[@class="container9"]/div[@class="ctl_aboutbrand"]/h1/text()').extract()
    price = hxs.select('//span[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Price_ctl00_spnWebPrice"]/span[@class="offer"]/span[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Price_ctl00_lblOfferPrice"]/text()').extract()
    prc = price[0].replace("Rs.  ","")
    description = []

    item['price'] = prc
    item['title'] = title
    item['description'] = description
    item['url'] = response.url

    return item
```

Answer (score 23):

yes you can do this simply by adding meta values like

```
meta={'dont_redirect': True}
```

also you can stop redirected for a particular response code like

```
meta={'dont_redirect': True,"handle_httpstatus_list": [302]}
```

it will stop redirecting only 302 response codes. you can add as many http status code you want to avoid redirecting them.

example

```
yield Request('some url',
    meta = {
        'dont_redirect': True,
        'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]
    },
    callback= self.some_call_back)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! but Im a bit confused as to where to put this line of code? I tried to overwrite the start_requests, but it gives me an error "Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'". Can we return an item and request at the same time?

Comment: You can call  hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) with redirect you would have to test response.status ==302 and do another kind of processing. The hxs in that case will fail because response.body is empty for 302 status

Comment: Has somebody tested? it is not working with the current scrapy version, I have tested with `'handle_httpstatus_list': [404, 301]` just 404 works

Comment: It stops redirecting, but it also doesn't crawl content from the given pages too, any solutions?

Comment: You can put this code into start_requests method into spider class. When spider is executed firstly start in init method and then go to start_requests and in this point the request hasn't send yet. You can put this:
        `request = Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse)
        request.meta['dont_redirect'] = True

        return [request]`
and then it will send the request and if it is ok will go to parse method, or callback method.

Answer (score 12):

After looking at the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) and looking through the relevant source, I was able to figure it out. If you look in the source for start_requests, you'll see that it calls make_requests_from_url for all URLs.

Instead of modifying start_requests, I modified make_requests_from_url

```
def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    return Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta = {
        'dont_redirect': True,
        'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]
    })
```

And added this as part of my spider, right above `parse()`.

Comment: I tried this but I still get redirected to the page I don't want

Comment: Lovely solution for the site I want to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

By default, Scrapy use `RedirectMiddleware` to handle redirection. You can set `REDIRECT_ENABLED` to False to disable redirection.

See [documentation](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect).

Comment: I tried, If I set "REDIRECT_ENABLED=False", the scrapy stop redirect, and also can not get the html content.

Answer (score 3):

As explained here: [Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-dont_redirect)

Use Request Meta

```
request =  scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse2)
request.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
yield request
```