# scrapy - restart scrapoxy instances?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have set up a proxy using [scrapoxy](http://scrapoxy.io/)
I have tried to set very conservative settings, hitting the target not so frequently, following the hints [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) although I am not sure I understand what it is meant by

> rotate your user agent from a pool of well-known ones from browsers
>   (google around to get a list of them)

this is my current settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

BOT_NAME = 'mybot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ffscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ffscraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'myUnivProject'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 5

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 20.0

# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 30
RETRY_TIMES = 0

# PROXY
PROXY = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8888/?noconnect'

# SCRAPOXY
API_SCRAPOXY = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8889/api'
API_SCRAPOXY_PASSWORD = 'xxxx'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapoxy.downloadmiddlewares.proxy.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapoxy.downloadmiddlewares.wait.WaitMiddleware': 101,
    'scrapoxy.downloadmiddlewares.scale.ScaleMiddleware': 102,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
}


# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'ffscraper.middlewares.FfscraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'ffscraper.middlewares.FfscraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'ffscraper.pipelines.FfscraperPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

I still, only after ~50 requests or so, start getting redirected to a page with a captcha.

```
2019-01-04 00:17:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET https://www.asite.com/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx&httpReferrer=xxxx> from <GET https://www.asite.com/xxx/xxx>
```

Blocking redirection as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476587/scrapy-how-to-stop-redirect-302) is not an option. I would need to be able to resume activity. Currently the only thing I can do is stopping the crawler, killing the VMs on scrapoxy, and restarting the scraper.

- Am I missing the elephant in the room? Is there something I could
  change in my settings?
- Alternatively, is there a way to programmatically shut down a VM and recreate one on redirection?

What is interesting is that if I block redirection

```
yield scrapy.Request(
                    url="https://www.whatasite.com" + url.split("?")[0],
                    meta={"name": name, 'dont_redirect': True,},
                    callback=self.parse
                    )
```

I then get `200` and a page I am not able to scrape (getting therefore empty values), instead of capturing an error code I could perhaps handle as in [here](https://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/python-scrapy-blacklisting/index.html).

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is your current issue and what is expected result? After X amount of time your proxies start to get captcha and after restart they are good as new?

Comment: After ~50 requests the proxies start to get redirected to a page with captchas. When the crawler is stopped, it scales down the proxies (kills the VMs) so after restart (with new VM) we are back to square one. Alternative1: do you see something else I could try that might be missing from my settings.py? A2: any other idea?

Comment: What does VD stand for?

Comment: venerial disease.

Comment: Seems like your question is a bit too broad. I don't really see anything bad with your config other than your USER_AGENT setting but I think scrapoxy middleware overrides it, at least judging by their website. How many proxies do you have and what's your crawl rate?