# Scrapy Stop Redirect and get the html content of current url

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-302

I want my scraper to stop redirect and try the same URL again. How can I do that?

I have tried `meta={'dont_redirect': True}`. But it ignores the request to current URL. I want the HTML content of the current URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrapy- how to stop Redirect (302)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476587/scrapy-how-to-stop-redirect-302)

Comment: When I set meta={'dont_redirect': True} it stop redirecting but also does not get the hml content. I want the HTML content

Comment: create minimal working code with real URL which makes problem. And then we can test it to see where is the problem.

Comment: Did you also set `httpstatus_list` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477884/939364 ?

Comment: Any results on that? I have the same problem where the url gets redirected. When I handle it with the httpstatus_list some attributes do not get parsed although they exist on the page.